# How to set up ssh communication with Bitbucket using Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, ssh, mercurial, bitbucket

I am following [this tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678) on establishing the ssh communication.

Everything goes fine until I get to:

**Step 7. Change your repo from HTTPS to the SSH protocol**

[image]

I have no idea what the first step means. I have no `.hg` folder and if I create one using `hg init`, there is no `hgrc` file in it.

I came to a new location and I want to **clone** repositories from **Bitbucket** using **ssh** to start working.

Also I have no idea what is meant by **myquotefork**. It does not appear in the previous text.

Comment: @Downvoter, please could you provide a suggestion how to improve my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply just want to clone an existing repository from Bitbucket using SSH instead of HTTPS, that is quite simple. From the command line on your local computer (where you want the repository cloned to), write the following command:

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/claims/nodatime
```

You will now have the repository cloned to the *nodatime* folder. And inside the nodatime folder, you should also have a *.hg* folder containing a *hgrc* file with the content described in point 3 in your question.

I haven't read the tutorial you're following, but point 1 expects that you've already cloned an existing repository. The *.hg* folder is created when you initialize/clone a repository. The *hgrc* file inside this folder is however *only* created when you *clone* an existing repo (and not when you just initialize one), which is probably why you didn't see it.